# Конструкция require_once ломает всю вёрстку

Tags: php, mvc

Пытаюсь писать код в стиле MVC. И как только добавляю `require_once "../header.php"`, то ломается вёрстка.
Пример view:

```
<?php    
$header = require_once '../header.php';
$mtar = require_once '../mtar.php';    
return "
$header
$mtar   
<div class='wrap'>
        <div id='content'>
            <div class='column-left'>";
```

В таком варианте на экран в html выдётся сначала всё, что перечислено в `require_once`, а уже затем представление самой страницы. Короче говоря, выдаётся в нарушении логики page.php:

```
<?php
return "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- здесь meta и проч скрипты -->    

$pageData->content
$pageData->scriptElements

</body>
</html>";
```

Если убрать из кода `require_once`, то вёрстка будет без ошибок. Подскажите, как правильно включить `../header.php`, `../footer.php` и другие файлы?

Comment: Проблема найдена, придёт время, попробую сформулировать. Включаемый файл имел html разбавленый php. А мои view страницы выводились через return " ";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Пользуйтесь функциями или классами для формирования блоков
2. `require_once` возвращает `true` если файл успешно загружен

Например в вашем случае:

**blocks.php**

```
<?php
function printHeader($options) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- здесь meta и проч скрипты -->    
<?php
    echo $options->content;
    echo $options->scriptElements;
}
// ... дальше другие функции
```

**page.php**

```
require_once("blocks.php");
printHeader($pageData);
// что-то выводим на страницу
printFooter($pageData);
```

PS. Кстати верстка ломается в первую очередь из-за того, что вы закрываете теги `body` и `html` в "хедере"

Comment: require_once при первом подключении файла может вернуть то, что идет в файле в конструкции return (что и происходит).

Comment: Согласен. Перечитал доки, вы правы. Только никогда и нигде не видел такого применения и не могу придумать когда это может понадобиться так чтобы это был единственно возможный вариант или хотя бы самый разумный

Comment: Здесь, конечно, необходимость под вопросом, но часто таким образом приложения получают конфиг, который сразу пишется в виде PHP-массива (впрочем, это тоже очень зря).

Comment: Благодарю за информацию. Всё верно. Просто начал делать MVC по книге PHP for Absolute Beginners 2 изд. и настолько увлёкся, что не могу остановиться и сменить этот шаблон. С кодом всё удобно, но вот с html не очень. Если вместо кода во view  ( $html = "<h1>Заголовок</h1>; return $html - поставить просто html код, то будут на странице выводиться 1 (единицы) как результат вывода return.

Answer (score 1):

```
$header = require_once '../header.php';
$mtar = require_once '../mtar.php';
```

Заменить на

```
$header = file_get_contents('../header.php');
$mtar = file_get_contents( '../mtar.php' );
```

Либо убрать `$header` и `$mtar` из html

MVC тут у тебя и не пахнет, рекомендую ознакомиться с каким-нибудь фреймворком

Comment: file_get_contents прекрасно сработал, но он не обработал php скрипты внутри header.php. Такие вставки в html вылезли: `<?
require_once 'domains-check.php';
?>`

Comment: убери переменные `$header` и `$mtar` из html и все. вообще такую фигню не надо творить, посмотри фреймворки, шаблонизаторы

Answer (score 1):

Делай только так:

```
require_once '../header.php';
require_once '../mtar.php';
```

И только в тех местах, где данный файл должен выводиться. Не нужно запихивать в переменную файлы, которые должны просто сразу выводиться.

Comment: Да всё верно. Если сделать 1 файл index.php и засунуть туда html, require_once (хидер, футер и проч) всё прекрасно выводит. Но когда index.php явялется контролером, то добавление require_once почему-то вылазит на странице в самый верх начинаяся не с <html> а с <body> и так далее. И дело в том, что внешние файлы, к которым у меня нет доступа (../header.php) добавляются криво, а свои файлы с html через include_once добавляются правильно. Не хочу ломать mvc, хочу разобраться. p.s. Учился по apress:php for absolute beginners.

Comment: // Часть кода index.php:
`$pageData->content .= include_once "views/header.php";
$pageData->content .= include_once "views/search-form-html.php";
$pageData->content .= include_once "controllers/$controller.php";

$page = include_once "views/page.php";
echo $page;`

Comment: Выше код формирует нужную страницу без ошибок. Но если перед этим кодом вставить `$pageData->content .= include_once "../header.php";` То на глаз будет всё ладно, а вёрстка поломана! Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо в тех подключаемых файлах стоит просто вывод текста, а не возвращается значение — в этом проблема. Сделайте как-то единообразно: либо только через return, либо только вывод. Рекомендую в шаблоне вывода всегда выводить, а не возвращать. Когда понадобится перехватить вывод, используйте буферизацию.

content.php

```
content
content
content
content
```

layout.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>…</head>
<body>
  <?= $content ?>
  <p>&copy; 2015 artoodetoo
</body>
</html>
```

view.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'conent.php';
$content = ob_get_clean();
include 'layout.php';
```